# Larger vs smaller areas for analysis: how to make a choice?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, sampling, regression-coefficients, geostatistics

I am researching the composition of labour force, and my variable of interest is the share of workers in a specific occupational category. I measure it by parish and also measure a set of explanatory variables. I can also make the same measurements for a larger geographic area, which is a district. Which unit of analysis would be more appropriate? The sample size is not particularly important, as there are 11,000 parishes and 1,700 districts. The analysis of variation has shown that the variance between parishes within a district is 0.2, and the variance between districts is 0.3. Does this observation indicate that one unit of analysis can be preferred to the other? If this information is not sufficient to make a decision, what other data are needed?

Comment: It would help to know how many people are in each parish on average and in the smallest one. And also approximately what proportion are in the occupational category you are interested in. If it is an unusual category, then it will be hard to get a good estimate without a lot of data.

Comment: This category is relatively large and contains ~ 25% of all workers. To be more precise, there are on average 84 workers per parish, and 21 of them are in the selected category. The corresponding figures for a district are 571 and 146.

Answer (score 0):

Given your comment, I would lean towards using districts. Since parishes have only 84 workers (on average), estimates of proportions are going to be fairly loose.

Unless you suspect that parishes within districts are really different from each other and you are interested in those differences.

Comment: Thank you, Peter! This is my impression too, I just wonder if there is a way to quantify the difference between the two approaches. Is there a way to quantify the advantages of moving to larger units?

Comment: You can look at the relative margins of error of estimating the % ages in smaller and larger samples.